# Expanding Meteor.User collection with collection2 and autoform

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2

I've been stuck with this problem for a day and a half now. What I'm trying to do is create a userProfile section into my Meteor.User collection. So, when the user lands on the 'settings' page they could update their information. Here is what I have down.

*By the way I'm using the [User Accounts](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md) package for the signin/signup procedure.*

**Update: 3**
The form submits but no data gets inserted/updated. I have commented out the 'Schema.User' because if i put it in and attach it to the Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.User). The auto form loads the fields. Which is why I put Schema.UserProfile instead. I checked the console log and it gives me the error "[Access Denied] 403" It must be an allow/deny conflict? I have every code listed on here.

**Settings HTML:**

```
<template name="settings">
<div class="text-center light-container" id="settings-section">
    {{> quickForm collection="Meteor.users" doc=currentUser id="userProfile" type="update"}}
</div>
```

**Settings JS In Both Directory**

```
    Schema = {};

Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
    userProfile: {
        type: Object
    },
    'userProfile.firstName':{
        type: String,
        label: "First Name",
        max: 80
    },
    'userProfile.lastName':{
        type: String,
        label: "Last Name",
        max: 80
    },
    'userProfile.gender':{
        type: String,
        label: "Gender",
        allowedValues: ["Male", "Female"]
    },
    'userProfile.birthday':{
        type: Date,
        label: "Date Of Birth",
        autoform: {
            type: "bootstrap-datepicker"
        }
    },
    address:{
        type: Object
    },
    'address.city':{
        type: String,
        label: "City/Province",
        max: 80
    },
    'address.state':{
        type: String,
        label: "State",
        max: 80
    },
    'address.country':{
        type: String,
        label: "Country",
        max: 80
    },
    /*privacy:{
        type: String,
        label: "Privacy",
        allowedValues: ["On", "Off"]
    }, */
    aboutYou:{
        type: String,
        label: "About You",
        autoform: {
            afFieldInput: {
                type: "textarea"
            }
        },
        max: 400
    },
    socialNetworks:{
        type: Object,
        label: "Social Networks"
    },
    'socialNetworks.facebook':{
        type: String,
        label: "Facebook",
        autoform: {
            placeholder: 'Username'
        },
        max: 50
    },
    'socialNetworks.instagram':{
        type: String,
        label: "Instagram",
        autoform: {
            placeholder: 'Username'
        },
        max: 50
    },
    'socialNetworks.tumblr':{
        type: String,
        label: "Tumblr",
        autoform: {
            placeholder: 'Username'
        },
        max: 50
    },
    'socialNetworks.twitter':{
        type: String,
        label: "Twitter",
        autoform: {
            placeholder: 'Username'
        },
        max: 50
    }
});


/* 
    Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
        username: {
            type: String,
            regEx: /^[a-z0-9A-Z_]{3,15}$/,
            optional: true
        },
        emails: {
            type: [Object],
            // this must be optional if you also use other login services like facebook,
            // but if you use only accounts-password, then it can be required
            optional: true
        },
        "emails.$.address": {
            type: String,
            regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
        },
        "emails.$.verified": {
            type: Boolean
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: Date
        },
        profile: {
            type: Schema.UserProfile,
            optional: true
        },
        services: {
            type: Object,
            optional: true,
            blackbox: true
        }/*,

        // Add `roles` to your schema if you use the meteor-roles package.
        // Option 1: Object type
        // If you specify that type as Object, you must also specify the
        // `Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP` group whenever you add a user to a role.
        // Example:
        // Roles.addUsersToRoles(userId, ["admin"], Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP);
        // You can't mix and match adding with and without a group since
        // you will fail validation in some cases.
        roles: {
            type: Object,
            optional: true,
            blackbox: true
        }

        */
    }); 

*/

Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.UserProfile);

Meteor.users.allow({
    insert: function(userId, doc) {
        // only allow posting if you are logged in
        console.log("doc: " + doc + " userId: " + userId);
        return !! userId;
    },
    update: function(userId, doc) {
        // only allow updating if you are logged in
        console.log("doc: " + doc + " userId: " + userId);
        return !! userId;
    },
    remove: function(userID, doc) {
        //only allow deleting if you are owner
        return doc.submittedById === Meteor.userId();
    }
});
```

**Settings JS in Client Directory**

```
/*
    var postHooks = {
        before: {
            insert: function(doc) {
                if(Meteor.userId()){
                    doc.userId = Meteor.userId();
                }

                return doc;
            }
        },
        docToForm: function(doc) {
            if (_.isArray(doc.tags)) {
                doc.tags = doc.tags.join(", ");
            }
            return doc;
        },
        formToDoc: function(doc) {
            if (typeof doc.tags === "string") {
                doc.tags = doc.tags.split(",");
            }
            return doc;
        }
    };

    AutoForm.addHooks('UserProfile', postHooks);

*/
```

If anyone can point me into the right direction that would be really helpful!!

Comment: So how can I implement it? How should I code it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a schema for your profile and then assign it to the user object's schema in the `profile` field.  I've done it for you below.

```
var Schema = {};

Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
   firstName:{
        type: String,
        label: "First Name",
        max: 80
    },
    lastName:{
        type: String,
        label: "Last Name",
        max: 80
    },
    gender:{
        type: String,
        label: "Gender",
        allowedValues: ["Male", "Female"]
    },
    birthday:{
        type: Date,
        label: "Date Of Birth",
        autoform: {
            type: "bootstrap-datepicker"
        }
    },
    address:{
        type: Object
    },
    'address.city':{
        type: String,
        label: "City/Province",
        max: 80
    },
    'address.state':{
        type: String,
        label: "State",
        max: 80
    },
    'address.country':{
        type: String,
        label: "Country",
        max: 80
    },
    /*privacy:{
        type: String,
        label: "Privacy",
        allowedValues: ["On", "Off"]
    }, */
    aboutYou:{
        type: String,
        label: "About You",
        autoform: {
            afFieldInput: {
                type: "textarea"
            }
        },
        max: 400
    },
    socialNetworks:{
        type: Object,
        label: "Social Networks"
    },
    'socialNetworks.facebook':{
        type: String,
        label: "Facebook",
        autoform: {
            placeholder: 'Username'
        },
        max: 50
    },
    'socialNetworks.instagram':{
        type: String,
        label: "Instagram",
        autoform: {
            placeholder: 'Username'
        },
        max: 50
    },
    'socialNetworks.tumblr':{
        type: String,
        label: "Tumblr",
        autoform: {
            placeholder: 'Username'
        },
        max: 50
    },
    'socialNetworks.twitter':{
        type: String,
        label: "Twitter",
        autoform: {
            placeholder: 'Username'
        },
        max: 50
   }
});

Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        regEx: /^[a-z0-9A-Z_]{3,15}$/,
        optional: true
    },
    emails: {
        type: [Object],
        // this must be optional if you also use other login services like facebook,
        // but if you use only accounts-password, then it can be required
        optional: true
    },
    "emails.$.address": {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
    },
    "emails.$.verified": {
        type: Boolean
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date
    },
    profile: {
        type: Schema.UserProfile,
        optional: true
    },
    services: {
        type: Object,
        optional: true,
        blackbox: true
    },
    // Add `roles` to your schema if you use the meteor-roles package.
    // Option 1: Object type
    // If you specify that type as Object, you must also specify the
    // `Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP` group whenever you add a user to a role.
    // Example:
    // Roles.addUsersToRoles(userId, ["admin"], Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP);
    // You can't mix and match adding with and without a group since
    // you will fail validation in some cases.
    roles: {
        type: Object,
        optional: true,
        blackbox: true
    }
});

Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.User);
```

For your allow and deny rules, you may want to makes sure that the userId matches the _id of the document instead of just seeing if they are logged in.

Comment: Hey I've updated my code but it's still broken. I've edited my original post with how I have it coded.

Comment: I think you need to pass something other than `this` to something else in your template as well.

Comment: Okay, so I had my **settings.js file** in my client folder. I submitted the form and all of the data gets passed onto the url. I check my collection and no insertion has been made. I then moved my **settings.js** file into a both directory and same problem.

The problem is that after submission the page refreshes and all of the data gets passed onto the url.

Comment: define a template helper to return the user doc that you want to edit, I am not sure what your data context is in this situation.

Comment: I've tried implementing a auto hook to the auto form but nothing. How would i write the template helper?

**btw** I updated the code again as seen above.

Comment: Now whenever I submit the form.  It sends but nothing gets inserted/updated on the Meteor.User collection.

Comment: You need `Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.User)` not `Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.UserProfile)`. Also, in your template, try `doc=currentUser` instead of `doc=this`.

Comment: @DeanBrettle Whenever I attach the `Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.User)` those fields load onto my auto form along with my UserProfile fields which is why I just put 'Schema.UserProfile'. I have changed the `this` to `currentUser` and still nothing gets submitted but I checked my console log and I finally get an error I want to see. It's "[Access Denied] 403". Which means it might have something to do with my allow/deny calls? I've updated the code so feel free to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (search for "NOTE" for comments describing the relevant changes):

**Settings HTML:**

```
<template name="settings">
<div class="text-center light-container" id="settings-section">
    {{! NOTE: the fields attribute tells quickForm which fields to display }}
    {{> quickForm collection="Meteor.users" fields="userProfile" doc=currentUser id="userProfile" type="update"}}
</div>
```

**Settings JS In Both Directory**

```
Schema = {};

Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
    userProfile: {
        type: Object
    },
    'userProfile.firstName':{
        type: String,
        label: "First Name",
        max: 80
    },
    'userProfile.lastName':{
        type: String,
        label: "Last Name",
        max: 80
    },
    'userProfile.gender':{
        type: String,
        label: "Gender",
        allowedValues: ["Male", "Female"]
    },
    'userProfile.birthday':{
        type: Date,
        label: "Date Of Birth",
        autoform: {
            type: "bootstrap-datepicker"
        }
    },
    address:{
        type: Object
    },
    'address.city':{
        type: String,
        label: "City/Province",
        max: 80
    },
    'address.state':{
        type: String,
        label: "State",
        max: 80
    },
    'address.country':{
        type: String,
        label: "Country",
        max: 80
    },
    /*privacy:{
        type: String,
        label: "Privacy",
        allowedValues: ["On", "Off"]
    }, */
    aboutYou:{
        type: String,
        label: "About You",
        autoform: {
            afFieldInput: {
                type: "textarea"
            }
        },
        max: 400
    },
    socialNetworks:{
        type: Object,
        label: "Social Networks"
    },
    'socialNetworks.facebook':{
        type: String,
        label: "Facebook",
        autoform: {
            placeholder: 'Username'
        },
        max: 50
    },
    'socialNetworks.instagram':{
        type: String,
        label: "Instagram",
        autoform: {
            placeholder: 'Username'
        },
        max: 50
    },
    'socialNetworks.tumblr':{
        type: String,
        label: "Tumblr",
        autoform: {
            placeholder: 'Username'
        },
        max: 50
    },
    'socialNetworks.twitter':{
        type: String,
        label: "Twitter",
        autoform: {
            placeholder: 'Username'
        },
        max: 50
    }
});

// NOTE: You need to use this schema because it is the schema for the collection you are updating.
Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        regEx: /^[a-z0-9A-Z_]{3,15}$/,
        optional: true
    },
    emails: {
        type: [Object],
        // this must be optional if you also use other login services like facebook,
        // but if you use only accounts-password, then it can be required
        optional: true
    },
    "emails.$.address": {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
    },
    "emails.$.verified": {
        type: Boolean
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date
    },
    profile: {
        type: Schema.UserProfile,
        optional: true
    },
    services: {
        type: Object,
        optional: true,
        blackbox: true
    }/*,

    // Add `roles` to your schema if you use the meteor-roles package.
    // Option 1: Object type
    // If you specify that type as Object, you must also specify the
    // `Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP` group whenever you add a user to a role.
    // Example:
    // Roles.addUsersToRoles(userId, ["admin"], Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP);
    // You can't mix and match adding with and without a group since
    // you will fail validation in some cases.
    roles: {
        type: Object,
        optional: true,
        blackbox: true
    }

    */
}); 

// NOTE: Meteor.users is a collection of objects matching the Schema.user schema, so you need to use this schema.
Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.User);

Meteor.users.allow({
    /* NOTE: The client should not be allowed to add users directly!
    insert: function(userId, doc) {
        // only allow posting if you are logged in
        console.log("doc: " + doc + " userId: " + userId);
        return !! userId;
    },
    */
    update: function(userId, doc, fieldNames) {
        // only allow updating if you are logged in
        console.log("doc: " + doc + " userId: " + userId);
        // NOTE: a user can only update his own user doc and only the 'userProfile' field
        return !! userId && userId === doc._id && _.isEmpty(_.difference(fieldNames, ['userProfile'])); 
    },
    /* NOTE: The client should not generally be able to remove users
    remove: function(userID, doc) {
        //only allow deleting if you are owner
        return doc.submittedById === Meteor.userId();
    }
    */
});
```

**Settings JS in Client Directory**

```
/* NOTE: I don't think you need any of these hooks.
    var postHooks = {
        before: {
            insert: function(doc) {
                if(Meteor.userId()){
                    doc.userId = Meteor.userId();
                }

                return doc;
            }
        },
        docToForm: function(doc) {
            if (_.isArray(doc.tags)) {
                doc.tags = doc.tags.join(", ");
            }
            return doc;
        },
        formToDoc: function(doc) {
            if (typeof doc.tags === "string") {
                doc.tags = doc.tags.split(",");
            }
            return doc;
        }
    };

    AutoForm.addHooks('UserProfile', postHooks);

*/
```